# React: How to bold words in an array of strings based on keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

Let's say I have an array of values that I need to filter through and return all values based on a `keyword` search and return 3 results.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Peach"];

array = array.filter(item => {
    return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
}).slice(0, 3)
```

What I am having trouble doing is **bolding** the term searched for each item. For instance, if i searched "a", I should return an array of jsx code where each time the "a" is listed in the results, it is bold:

```
[
    <span>B<strong>a</strong>n<strong>a</strong>n<strong>a</strong></span>,
    <span>Or<strong>a</strong>nge</span>,
    <span><strong>A</strong>pple</span>
]
```

I have tried something to the effect of:

```
array = array.map((item, index) => (
    <span>
        {item.split('a')} // then somehow join the a back with the strong tags
    </span>
));
```

also tried something like this, but the returned value is in string format and cannot to my knowledge converted to jsx:

```
array.map(item => {
    return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + term + ')', 'ig'), '<strong>$1</strong>');   
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could technically use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to convert the string into DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, you need to check if the element of the array *has* the search term then also split the element into letters to match for that term (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-earc4c)

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  var fruits = ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango', 'Peach', 'Blueberry'];

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'palegoldenrod' }}>
      {fruits.map(fruit => {
        if (/a/.test(fruit)) {
          return (
            <p>
              {fruit.split('').map(letter => {
                if (letter === 'a') {
                  return <strong>{letter}</strong>;
                }

                return letter;
              })}
            </p>
          );
        }

        return fruit;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... the way you solved it helped lead me to solve the issue i was having.

Answer (score 0):

@hunter-mcmillen pointed me in the right direction, which led me to the solution, all credit goes to him!!!  I may have misrepresented my problem a little... I needed to bold the word if it had the letter "a" in it. Below is what i was looking for, Thanks again Hunter!!!

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  var fruits = ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango', 'Peach', 'Blueberry'];

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'palegoldenrod' }}>
      {fruits.map(fruit => {
        if (/a/.test(fruit)) {
          return (
            <p>
              {fruit.split(' ').map(word => {
                if (word.indexOf('a') != -1) {
                  return <strong>{word}</strong>;
                }

                return word;
              })}
            </p>
          );
        }

        return fruit;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also want to mention a friend of mine solved this a different way:

```
let term = 'apple orange banana';
  let search = 'a';
  
  let parts = term.split(search);
  
  return parts.map((item, i) => (
    <>{item && <strong>{item}</strong>}{(i !== parts.length - 1) ? search : null}</>
  ))
```